# Creating a custom project type for Visual Studio to build Borland C++ Builder projects into Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, c++builder

I want to start the develop of a custom project type for Visual Studio that builds a BPR project with Visual Studio.

I need some hints to beginning with this project. Where can I find a template for this type of projects?

My target is to remove the Borland C++Builder's ugly and unstable interface from the development process and work enterely from Visual Studio.

Comment: Which version of C++Builder are you using?

Comment: Are you using the VCL or just C++ code?

Comment: I'm using Borland C++ Builder 5 and using VCL.

Answer (score 3):

Edit: Oops, I didn't really see that you're about to *create a new project type for C++ Builder files*. In that case, you have to build a language package. The [Visual Studio Extensibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsx/default.aspx) site should get you started. Also have a look at [this more specific link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166376.aspx).

I'll leave my old answer here for reference, because it might help people who just want to build C++Builder projects without creating a whole new project type :)

> You didn't specify the version of Visual Studio, but I'll assume a recent one. In Visual Studio 8 and 9, most project files (all popular ones except Visual C++) are actually MSBuild files and can therefore be built by MSBuild. You can add a simple command line task (Exec) to build your bpr on the command line, or you can create a custom task for this (if you don't find one already available - the search terms should be *MSBuild* and *custom task*). This way, both Visual Studio and MSBuild can build anything you like. If you don't have an MSBuild file to start with or want to dive into developing a task, the [MSBuild project template](http://www.codeplex.com/MSBuildTemplate) for Visual Studio will help you.
>
> Oh, and other than that, if you don't actually need C++Builder things, you might as well export the BPR as a solution (or create a new solution and add the files).

Comment: Thanks, I'm dealing with Visual Studio 2005 SDK now. My purpose is to mantain the application in Visual Studio too, not only build the files.

I copy the nested project sample of the SDK and I'm trying to modify to work with bpr files. I don't want to create the project files only open it to build.

Answer (score 0):

Integrating C++Builder projects into a build process should be a lot easier with C++Builder 2007 or 2009 as both use MSBuild as build system. But then, I think that upgrading to a recent version of C++Builder solves your problem the other way :)